# Make tailwindcss navbar component close on scroll

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have been trying to make this tailwind navbar component for react (code obtained from [site](https://codesandbox.io/s/dy13o)) close on scroll for mobile view but am not been able to make it work.=>>> [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/dy13o)

I tried implementing the following code obtained from another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69473259/how-to-show-or-hide-navbar-when-scroll-use-react-js) but its still not working. Someone please help.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Navbar = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
  const [lastScrollY, setLastScrollY] = useState(0);

  const controlNavbar = () => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') { 
      if (window.scrollY > lastScrollY) { // if scroll down hide the navbar
        setShow(false); 
      } else { // if scroll up show the navbar
        setShow(true);  
      }

      // remember current page location to use in the next move
      setLastScrollY(window.scrollY); 
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', controlNavbar);

      // cleanup function
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', controlNavbar);
      };
    }
  }, [lastScrollY]);

  return (
        <nav className={`active ${show && 'hidden'}`}>
        ....
        </nav>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using Tailwind CSS to conditionally apply classes to your navbar component based on the scroll behavior. If you want the navbar to close (or hide) when scrolling down and show when scrolling up, you're on the right track with the show state.

However, the class logic in your JSX seems a bit off. You're using the active class always, and the hidden class only when show is truthy. It might be more intuitive to use the hidden class when show is false. Here's a modified version of your component:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Navbar = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
  const [lastScrollY, setLastScrollY] = useState(0);

  const controlNavbar = () => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      if (window.scrollY > lastScrollY) {
        // if scrolling down, hide the navbar
        setShow(false);
      } else {
        // if scrolling up, show the navbar
        setShow(true);
      }

      // remember the current page location for the next move
      setLastScrollY(window.scrollY);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', controlNavbar);

      // cleanup function
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', controlNavbar);
      };
    }
  }, [lastScrollY]);

  return (
    <nav className={`fixed w-full transition-transform duration-300 transform ${show ? 'translate-y-0' : '-translate-y-full'}`}>
      {/* ... Your navbar content */}
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I'm using the translate-y-0 class to keep the navbar in its normal position when show is true and -translate-y-full to move it off-screen when show is false. This uses the transition-transform and duration-300 classes for a smooth transition effect.

Make sure you have Tailwind CSS properly configured in your project for these utility classes to work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `setShow(true)` in the `controlNavbar` function. Otherwise you just keep re-opening the navbar for no reason.

```js
const controlNavbar = () => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') { 
    if (window.scrollY > lastScrollY) { // if scroll down hide the navbar
      setShow(false); 
    } else {
      setShow(true);  
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Remove this line
    }

    // remember current page location to use in the next move
    setLastScrollY(window.scrollY); 
  }
};
```

And it's better to follow the eslint exhaustive-deps rules. So the code will be refactored to:

```js
const controlNavbar = useCallback(() => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    if (window.scrollY > lastScrollY) {
      // if scroll down hide the navbar
      setIsOpen(false);
    }
    // remember current page location to use in the next move
    setLastScrollY(window.scrollY);
  }
}, [lastScrollY]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', controlNavbar);

    // cleanup function
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', controlNavbar);
    };
  }
}, [controlNavbar]);
```